# chat names in msgstore.db whatsapp

Tags: android, whatsapp

I'm currently working on a little program which should give me some statistics about my whatsapp usage.

So my question is: 
Is there any way to get the names of whatsapp contacts whose chats are in the msgstore.db which i got from /data/data/com.whatsapp/databases?

So e.g if i have any Chat with anon, it only shows up in the table as "@s.whatsapp.net"

Is there any other database by WhatsApp which holds all the different chatnames or am i forced to export the contacts in my phone book and then associate the entry in the database with the phone numbers of the specific contact?

I hope i explained it understandable enough.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the display names from wa.db , table name is wa_contacts.Watsapp has two main databases. msgstore.db and wa.db. As you already know the messages reside in messages table and the corresponding contacts are in phonenumber@watsapp.net format and groups are adminphonenumber@watsapp.g.us. These ids are mapped with the names in wa_contacts table.

Answer (score -1):

No its not possible android does not allow to read any other application database. As every application Runs in its own sand box.

Comment: The program won't be a Android application it's a Java apllication but it uses the msgstore.db. so i habe the database on my PC but now i have to know the names behind the telephone numbers.